# Need to transfer site currently on Siteground

Tags: wordpress, ftp, file-transfer, transfer

my client wants to keep using their hosting that they currently have their site on, where I was given cpanel and ftp logins. I made the Wordpress site on a temporary domain on Siteground. How do I go about transferring the site to their hosting?

Answer (score 0):

there are many plugins to transfer your website **and** database to different hosting. The good one also rename all URL's in your database to ones of your new hosting.

I suppose the easiest one is Akeeba backup for Wordpress [Akeeba Backup for WordPress](https://www.akeeba.com/download.html#akeebabackup-wordpress)

1. **download** the plugin, install it in your Wordpress and activate it
2. In your Wordpress menu you will have Akeeba backup entry click it and create new backup (for bigger websites I recommend split the backup file into smaller parts in plugin settings)
3. upload **all parts** of your newly created backup (you will find it in wp-content/plugins/akeebabackupwp/app/backups/) into the new server root through FTP
4. download Akeeba Kickstart [Kickstart (Standalone)](https://www.akeeba.com/download.html#kickstart) (this files will uncompress your backup on the server) so **copy both files** in downloaded zip into server root
5. visit in your browser your new hosting domain and **add /kickstart.php** (example.com/kickstart.php) follow onscreen instruction to complete recovery

in case you are stuck here documentation for Akeeba Backup [Akeeba Backup for WordPress](https://www.akeeba.com/videos/1215-akeeba-backup-wordpress/1647-abtw01-installation-first-backup.html)

and for [akeeba-kickstart](https://www.akeeba.com/support/site-restoration/Tickets.html)